# Why does ariflow's log on google cloud composer suddenly error caused by '[Errno -2] name or service not know'?

Tags: logging, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I use google cloud composer for airflow to monitor workflow. After some of the workflow, suddenly the log doesn't come up on airflow UI. Here is the error on airflow UI

```
*** Log file isn't local.

*** Fetching here: http://xxxxx:8793/log/etl-job-bq/influxdb_internet_usage_task/2019-10-01T01:05:00/2.log

*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxxxx', port=8793): Max retries exceeded with url: /log/etl-job-bq/influxdb_internet_usage_task/2019-10-01T01:05:00/2.log (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1a5f0d66d8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Then, I tried to look into GCS for the airflow log and the log was there. But the airflow from google cloud composer failed to fetch log file on GCS

Comment: Please post the [mcve] that produces this error. See [ask]

Comment: @xiawi thank you for your information, I just edit the question

Comment: @EnriqueZetina thank you, but I can't open it caused account not found